# Listen to panel height change gwt

Tags: events, gwt, listener, panel

Does anybody know about a way to listen to height, width, or globally **size change** of a panel widget?
Thanks

Comment: Please look at this It may be help (seems like a repeated question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241084/adding-resize-listener-handler-to-verticalpanel-in-gwt

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I'm not trying to do the same thing, but at least I see that it's impossible to detect it ... ma be I've got to change my strategy

Comment: There may be chance to add custom event, i am not sure that's why not put it in answer.

Comment: Seems like the problem comes from the browser that doesn't event detect size changes, ad creating anew event needs a new type of panel to trigger it (not so generic solution)

Comment: hmm so you got your answer good :)